How to Create a Data Frame or Table Summarizing Multiple Question Types?
I am trying to create a summarized data frame or table that encompasses different descriptive information for different categories of questions.
For example, here is some of the raw data:

What I would like to be able to do is create 3 different types of summarized tables.
In the first case, I have some questions that are simply Yes/No, and will always be one of those responses. For those types of questions, I am looking for something like this:

In the second case, I have some questions that will always be numerical, and would like some basic descriptive information for those. So for those questions I am looking for something like this:

In the third case, I have a couple "Check all that apply" questions that have left me with multiple selections within a single cell separated by ";" I would like to separate those options out, and create a similar table to the first table above. So something like this:

The closest I have gotten to creating one of these tables is using dplyr in R with something like:
df %>%
   count(Q1) %>%
   mutate(Percent=round(n/sum(n)*100,1))

However, that is only giving me the info for one question rather than a set of similar questions.
I am trying to create all of this using dplyr so I can programmatically update these tables as more responses come in.
Here is some toy data:
read.table(text= "TestID    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6
1   Y   35  A;B;C   N   40  X;Y;Z
2   N   32  B;C Y   38  X;Y
3   Y   22  B   Y   28  X
4   Y   38  A;B Y   46  Z
5   Y   13  A   N   9   Y
6   N   30  A;B N   21  Y;Z
7   N   36  A;C N   46  X;Z
8   Y   30  B;C Y   39  X;Z
9   Y   33  B   N   39  X
10  N   20  C   Y   19  Y
11  N   28  A;B Y   37  Y
12  N   28  A;B;C   N   23  X
13  Y   28  A   Y   30  X
14  Y   21  B;C Y   26  Y;Z
15  N   14  A;B N   7   X;Y", 
           header = T, stringsAsFactors = F) -> df


We need to break this into two operations and summarize the numeric columns and character ones separately. Here's an attempt:
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  select(where(is.numeric), -TestID) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Q") %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(value), 
            Min = min(value),
            Max = max(value), 
            .by = Q)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   Q      Mean   Min   Max
#>   <chr> <dbl> <int> <int>
#> 1 Q2     27.2    13    38
#> 2 Q5     29.9     7    46

df %>% 
  select(where(~!is.numeric(.x))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Q", values_to = "Response") %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(Response, ";") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Response) | Response != "") %>% 
  summarise(Frequency = n(), 
            .by = c(Q, Response)) %>% 
  bind_rows(., summarise(.,
                         Response = "Total",
                         Frequency = sum(Frequency), 
                         .by = Q)) %>% 
  arrange(Q) %>% 
  mutate(Percent = scales::percent(Frequency / max(Frequency)), .by = Q)

#> # A tibble: 14 × 4
#>    Q     Response Frequency Percent
#>    <chr> <chr>        <int> <chr>  
#>  1 Q1    Y                8 53.3%  
#>  2 Q1    N                7 46.7%  
#>  3 Q1    Total           15 100.0% 
#>  4 Q3    A                9 33.3%  
#>  5 Q3    B               11 40.7%  
#>  6 Q3    C                7 25.9%  
#>  7 Q3    Total           27 100.0% 
#>  8 Q4    N                7 46.7%  
#>  9 Q4    Y                8 53.3%  
#> 10 Q4    Total           15 100.0% 
#> 11 Q6    X                9 39.1%  
#> 12 Q6    Y                8 34.8%  
#> 13 Q6    Z                6 26.1%  
#> 14 Q6    Total           23 100.0%

Created on 2024-07-05 with reprex v2.0.2
